# Can't write text files to documents folder in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-12

I have an app that I am trying to write values from my camera to a text file.

Yesterday, I was able to solve this issue: [How to write and constantly update a text file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045965/how-to-write-and-constantly-update-a-text-file-in-android?noredirect=1#comment129025130_73045965), although after re-installing I am no longer able to write files to documents directory.

I am getting the following exception:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/1658486312697.txt: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Writting code:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
try {
    File outFile1 = new File(path+"/"+String.valueOf(time)+".txt");
    Log.e("outFile1:", outFile1.getAbsolutePath());
    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                 new FileOutputStream(outFile1,true), "utf-8"), 10240);
    for (int i = 10; i < 110602; i++) {
        out.write(values[i] + "\r\n");
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Permissions on `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am currently testing on Android 12 device
I'd like to know why can I not save my text files to documents and what needs to be done to save it the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because outFile1 doesn't exist.

```
File outFile1 = new File(path+"/"+String.valueOf(time)+".txt");
outFile1.createNewFile(); //add this line
```

And make sure you have allowed MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Application Setting. [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68140893/android-studio-throwing-ioexception-operation-not-permitted)

And also for below android 11 devices you have to ask for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission using "Permission Dialog". [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Comment: I was able to do it without the .createNewFile before. Besides, this still gives: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted

Comment: Make sure that you have allowed MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: It is already inserted in the AndroidManifest.xml as described above

Comment: just inserting in AndroidManifest.xml won't work, you have to write java code also, i have updated answer please check given link

Comment: Thanks for the information, I apologize for the down vote, it was a missclick. How can I fix it?

Comment: you can click on up arrow.

Comment: it said I already voted and can't upvote unless your answer is edited

Comment: for below android 11 devices i have updated the answer please check. and if possible up vote the answer.